# Is this proof written and structured well?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

How important is the structure of a proof? Is the proof below written well? I personally think the structure of the proof makes it easy to read, but I don't know what others think.

$\textbf{Claim: }$ If $f$ is injective, then $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$

$\textbf{Proof:}$

1. $\textbf{Preliminaries}$

- 1.1. $\textbf{Definition}$: A function $f$ is injective if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$.

2. $\textbf{First Implication}$

- 2.1. Assume $y\in f(A\cap B)$
- 2.2. Then, there exists $x\in A\cap B$ such that $f(x)=y$
- 2.3. It follows that $y\in f(A)$ and $y\in f(B)$
- 2.4. Therefore, $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$

3. $\textbf{Second Implication}$

- 3.1. Assume $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$
- 3.2. Then $y\in f(A)$ and $y\in f(B)$
- 3.3. There exists $x'\in A$ and $x''\in B$ such that $f(x')=y$ and $f(x'')=y$
- 3.4. By injectiveness (1.1), $x'=x''$
- 3.5. Hence, $x'$ (or $x''$) is in $A\cap B$, and $y\in f(A\cap B)$

4. $\textbf{Conclusion}$

- 4.1. Both directions $f( A\cap B) \subseteq f( A) \cap f( B)$ and $f( A) \cap f( B) \subseteq f( A\cap B)$ have been proven
- 4.2. Hence, $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$

$\mathbf{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: It's fine, but I would write this out in paragraph form rather than with numbered lines, unless for some reason that's necessary.

Comment: Personal choice depends on the math sophistication of the reader.  I think that the proof is very well written.  Further, I think that for students new to the topic, your presentation is optimal.  That is, you are (in effect) very carefully justifying each step that you take.

Comment: (a) Sometimes, when students are first learning to write proofs, they are given some form like this to follow.  They soon grow to hate it. (b) There are a few computerized  "proof checkers", which take strictly formatted proofs like this, and check whether they are valid.  Perhaps you will find it rewarding to contribute to one of these efforts.  See https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com